# Running into memory issues when loading a composer layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, memory, windows-10

I'm trying to load a specific composer layout model, but it not respond properly, slowing down my computer, consuming all it's memory, to the the point of giving me no option but a Windows hard reset.

I've used this layout model in previous versions whit no problems at all.
Also, creating a new blank layout work's just fine.

I've try to overcome this situation by making a copy of a project that had already the layout in the composer manager, and, then, just adapt the layers and features.

It was possible to open the layout and work on it, but when I'd saved the project, close the composer, and try to re-open, I've got the same memory usage issue.

My configuration is:
Windows 10 Pro v 1903
QGIS 3.10.0

Comment: sounds like a bug. make a bug report. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: It really does. I'll make the report. Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Check please if you have a cross-type grid in CRS other then a map window.
I have Qgis crash everytime when i try to add a such cross-type grid.

Comment: In fact, I had. My map canvas was in EPSG 31983 and the map in composer was in EPSG 31982. Unfortunately, since I also had to finish a work in progress, I'd made a downgrade to 3.8.3, and won't be able to test your tip for now.

Comment: A curious fact is that, even in version 3.8.3, I can open any project saved previously in version 10.0.0 without a single problem. Not even a warning.